# Create a private tunnel for exchange data

Tags: networking, exchange, microsoft-outlook, blocking

Hypothetically, let's say I wanted to access my private email (or really just the calender) through my office network without installing anything on my work computer. Background; there used to be access to private emails through our office network until some less technical people decided it was a smart thing to open ransomware attachments and get their computers encrypted. I have had a private email added to Outlook - actually an @outlook.com address which have worked perfectly through the automatic exchange setup until now.

Is there any easy way to setup a service at my home computer or even my router for tunneling the exchange traffic through a not blocked ip? I would still want to access it through Outlook.

Current server:
https://outlook.office365.com/mapi/emsmdb/?MailboxId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com

To something like:
https://myprivateaddress/mapi/emsmdb/?MailboxId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com

Comment: This question might be better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: Agreed, this should be moved to SuperUser.